# regex include and exclude escape sequences

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression pattern that takes the following data:

```
static String testData = "0001,48;0451,0605\\,230001;0461,0606\\;230006;0431,0605230002";
```

and prints out to groups such as:

```
Group 1: 0001,48;
Group 2: 0451,0605\\,230001;
Group 3: 0461,0606\\;230006;
Group 4: 0431,0605230002;
```

The pattern I have currently is not efficent in parsing the escape sequence that appears in '0605\,230001'.

```
static String testPattern = "([\\d]{4}" + "[,]{1}"+ "(?:[[a-zA-Z0-9][\\;][\\,][\\(][\\)][\\s]]*)"+ "[;]{1})" ;
```

The above pattern is only efficient in printing as mentioned:

```
Group 1: 0001,48;
Group 2: 0431,0605230001;
```

Rest of the code:

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(testPattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testData);

System.out.println("Test Matches: "+testData.matches(testPattern));

while(matcher.find())
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Is there way where we can have the escape sequences in the pattern and also not escape them when we want it?

Comment: Why are you using regex to do this? It looks like you just want to split on ;

Comment: If @PeterMichealLacey-Bordeaux is correct, simply replace all "other" delimiters with ;

Comment: What happens when there is an '/;', i.e., ';' preceded by an escape character, will it be smart enough to detect the escape character and ignore it while splitting?

Comment: @Fardu Use a regex for the split in that case

Comment: I have just edited the input data, since there can be a lot many escape sequences that can appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested. you can use the [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to do this using a regex for the split.

See this sample here:

```
String testData = "0001,48;0451,0605\\,230001;0431,0605230002;";
String[] array = testData.split("(?<=[^\\]);");
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Which prints

```
"0001,48"
"0451,0605\\,230001"
"0431,0605230002"
```

Then if you have the testData as `""0001,48;0451,0605\\;230001;0431,0605230002;"` (notice the escaped `;`), it prints

```
"0001,48"
"0451,0605\\;230001"
"0431,0605230002"
```

If you require the semicolons on the end you could add them manually or use this regex which will retain the semicolons and only split on non escaped semicolons

```
"(?<=(?<=[^\\]);)"
```

Comment: Note that if the input is heavily escaped, the regex cannot detect and split incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you Java Devil for the quick response, I will still work on the split regular expression for my specific scenario.

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't get what you mean... Example?

Comment: See my post for example. I don't know whether OP has to deal with such input or not, though.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should work when you want to split the input into parts delimited by `;`:

```
"\\G([^;\\\\]|\\\\.)+;"
```

The regex above should be used with `Matcher.find()`. Note that you need record whether you have reached the end of input after the every match, so that you can check whether all input has been consumed.

This should work with even inputs that are heavily escaped (note that this is text, not Java string literal):

```
456\\\;734;82734\\\\;574\;347;
```

(As Java string literal: `"456\\\\\\;734;82734\\\\\\\\;574\\;347;"`)

will be split into:

```
456\\\;734;
82734\\\\;
574\;347;
```

If `;` is preceded by even number of `\`, it means that `\` escape itself, so `;` will not be escaped.

Comment: IMO Your example has split incorrectly. The third `;` is still escaped and should not split...

Comment: @JavaDevil: The 3rd one has even number of ``\`` (note that this is RAW string). The Java String literal is the "ready-for-testing" version.

Comment: Ahhh, yes I understand now. Yes in this case my regex fails then... but as you say depends if OP has to deal with this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code

```java
for(String str : testData.split("(?<=(?<!\\\\);)"))
{
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

It splits the string into separate pieces using String's [`.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method, then prints out each of the pieces.

If you need to implement the regex the way it is in your question, use this string for the regex:

```java
"+*?(?<=(?<!\\\\);)"
```

Explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/vW0oT9

Answer (score 0):

Adopted copy of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741861/1266906) to a different question.

While implementing your own `split()` function may seem like a overhead in the first place, my solution can correctly handle strings containing backslash-escaped semi-colons and backslashes like

```java
String input = "0001,48;0451,0605\\,230001\\\\;0461,0606\\;230006;0431,0605230002";
```

With example-usage:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Print {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String input = "0001,48;0451,0605\\,230001\\\\;0461,0606\\;230006;0431,0605230002";
        final String[] strings = splitValues(input);
        System.out.print("\""+input+"\" => ");
        printQuoted(strings);
    }

    public static String[] splitValues(final String input) {
        final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        // (?:\\\\)* matches any number of \-pairs
        // (?<!\\) ensures that the \-pairs aren't preceded by a single \
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*;");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        int previous = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            result.add(input.substring(previous, matcher.end()));
            previous = matcher.end();
        }
        result.add(input.substring(previous, input.length()));
        return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
    }

    public static void printQuoted(final String[] strings) {
        if (strings.length > 0) {
            System.out.print("[\"");
            System.out.print(strings[0]);
            for(int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
                System.out.print("\", \"");
                System.out.print(strings[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("\"]");
        } else {
            System.out.println("[]");
        }
    }
}
```

will print

> "0001,48;0451,0605\,230001\\;0461,0606\;230006;0431,0605230002" => ["0001,48;", "0451,0605\,230001\\;", "0461,0606\;230006;", "0431,0605230002"]

If you don't need the abbility to escape a backslash in front of a ; than you should be fine with the builtins and e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21536089/1266906).